# How To Charge a Battery in Falstad Circuit?

Tags: battery-charging, spice, falstad

I'd like to model the charging of a battery in Paul Falstad's [Circuit simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/). But, i cannot find a battery component.

Is there any way to do this?

thx

Comment: yes if you know the battery equiv cct like 10kF capacitance in series with the ESR for a crude model. First you need specs then a model. Normally I add a Vmin in series to represent initial voltage.

Comment: gee, i thought of how people substitute super-caps for batteries  :)  So, in series, Vmin (2-terminal DC source), cap set to F's equiv to desired aH, and resistor set to the battery's hypothetical ESR? i think i'm close- http://tinyurl.com/ycrh3ngd

Comment: No @johnywhy your model of a supercap and battery is wrong . A battery has a Vt minimum and two RC1//RC2 with values 1k~10k bigger in Farads than supercaps of same size but bigger ESR’s.

Answer (score 2):

Battery in falstad is just a voltage source, so you could put 2 voltage sources in a series - one larger than the other, and the plus side of one next to the plus side of another: - + + -.
Then the current passing through the second voltage source will be charging it.
The way you know it’s charging is that there’s a voltage drop across the 2nd smaller source in the direction of current flow. That voltage drop represents the energy the current loses to battery being charged.